# Why is it allowed to add primitive datatypes to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, object, integer, primitive-types

I understand that it is possible to add an Integer Object to an `ArrayList` of type `Integer`. That makes sense to me. Like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(new Integer(3));
```

But why is it possible to add a primitive datatype like int instead of `Integer`? Like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(3);
```

Why is that allowed??

Answer (score 17):

This is called [`autoboxing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). For classes that have corresponding primitives (e.g, `Long` -> `long`, `Integer` -> `int`), Java will handle the conversion for you.

It should be noted this behavior comes with some dark corners:

1. a performance penalty;
2. Corner cases: when `null` is unboxed into a primitive, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown, which might be unexpected for the programmer since it looks like a primitive is throwing the exception.

Comment: Unboxing null should be vanishingly rare and I'd prefer getting an exception if I put a null in a collection because that is usually not what you want in your code anyway.

Comment: @confusopoly I agree an exception is not bad, but when debugging the programmer could be confused (especially inexperienced individuals).

Comment: There are more dark corners: Certain primitive values, boxed multiple times, are guaranteed to result in the same object: booleans and `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int` types from -128 to 127. This is very arbitrary and has led to many misconceptions about boxing.

Comment: @newacct Agreed. Probably I should add a etc. in the end and link to some other sources. Is there any comprehensive article on the dark corners of boxing you might know of?